# Can you ensure delivery with one-way service methods?

Tags: c#, wcf, service, named-pipes, reliability

Say I have a proxy that sends a message to a WCF server:

```
NetNamedPipeBinding b = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);
b.MaxConnections = 1000000;
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(@"net.pipe://sendmessage");
channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ISendMessage>(b, address);
proxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
proxy.SendMessage("Hello, world.");
```

Say the SendMessage function has a one-way OperationContract:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
void SendMessage(string message);
```

Does running the line of code, `proxy.SendMessage("Hello, world.");` guarantee delivery of the message to the server? If not by default, is there a way to guarantee delivery? Say my application crashes, and it crashes right after `proxy.SendMessage("Hello, world.");` runs, will the message have made it to the server assuming no network glitches?

Comment: I think you're talking about `WCF`, not `WPF`. Those are 2 very different things. I have edited your question

Comment: @HighCore Yes, I mistagged it and misspelled it, seems I've been working them both a lot lately. My apologies. You are correct, WCF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-way operation ensures that your request is queued on service side. The main difference from request-reply operation is that client unblocks immediately after the server got the message without waiting for operation dispatching. Therefore, there is no way to know operation result, exceptions thrown or even the fact that operation was invoked.

You can read details here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx#S1

Comment: Great answer, Den. I have a follow-up question which is really important to me, what about if the server goes down or there is an interruption to the service that stops the message from going through? Will it throw exceptions in that case? My thoughts are that it will, since it blocks until the server gets the message, right?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the answer: "No return message also means that there can be no SOAP fault returned to indicate any errors in processing or communication. (Communicating error information when operations are one-way operations requires a duplex message exchange pattern.)" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733070(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Alexandru: I believe, you will get an exception only in case of network issues or if the server rejects message due to throttling settings.

Comment: But what about in the case of the server dying WHILE processing a message?

Comment: In that case you will not get an exception